# Unfriending someone through the Facebook API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-friends

Is it possible to remove a friend relationship between two FB users through the API? I'm thinking that it's not, but (if not) is it possible to at least bring up a dialog that would let the user request the unfriending, similar to how the Friends Dialog (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/friends/) lets a user send a friend invitation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any way to unfriend someone using Facebook's PHP SDK?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7555651/any-way-to-unfriend-someone-using-facebooks-php-sdk)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is not possible through the API. Facebook is like the mafia - you can get in. but there's no way out.

Simialar to this question:
[Any way to unfriend or delete a friend using Facebook's PHP SDK or API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7555651/any-way-to-unfriend-someone-using-facebooks-php-sdk)

Also, it is against the terms of service for facebook apps to ask people to unfriend. There was a BurgerKing prootional app that famously ran afoul of that after going viral.
http://www.insidefacebook.com/2009/01/14/whopper-sacrifice-shut-down-by-facebook/

Let friends unfriend on their own time.

Comment: You cannot remove friends with a friend dialog. If that feature was ever there, it is not any longer.

Comment: Thanks much.  Seems to be another instance of "This is X's world; we're just living in it."

Comment: Very interesting about the Burger King promo. +1.

Answer (score 5):

You can do that with a browser script:
[Deleteting All Facebook friend programmatically using fb graph api](http://yakobubaidullah.blogspot.fr/2012/05/deleteting-all-facebook-friend.html)

The script in this page is out of date, here's a working one:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN", // get this at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer take the Friends link and replace it.
  success: function(data) {
        jQuery.each(data.data, function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "https://m.facebook.com/a/removefriend.php",
                data: "friend_id="+this.id+"&fb_dtsg=AQC4AoV0&unref=profile_gear&confirm=Confirmer",
                async: false,
                type: "post"
                }
            })
        });
  },
  dataType: "json"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is 2021 working code, other methods i tried were obsolete.

1. Go to https://m.facebook.com/friends/center/friends and open browser console.
2. Execute jquery-min defintion code from https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js into browser console.
3. Run the following code from your brower console.

```js
// from https://m.facebook.com/friends/center/friends  
// first copy paste: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js


let ok = this.document 
let firstrec = ok.firstChild.nextSibling.firstChild.nextElementSibling.firstChild.nextElementSibling.firstChild.nextElementSibling.firstChild.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.nextElementSibling.firstElementChild nextrec = firstrec

// simulate click function async function clickf(div, entry) {
    if (entry == null) {
        await $(div).click()
        return await $(div).click()
    }
    if (entry == "0") {
        console.log("ehhe")
        await $(div)[0].click()browse
        return await $(div)[0].click()
    } }


function* removefb() {
    while (true) {
        nextclick = nextrec.firstElementChild.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.firstElementChild
        nextreccopy = nextrec
        nextrec = nextrec.nextSibling
        if (nextrec == null) {
            nextrec = nextreccopy
            nextrec = nextrec.parentElement.nextElementSibling.firstElementChild
        }
        clickf(nextclick)

        remover = nextclick.nextElementSibling.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.nextElementSibling.firstElementChild.nextElementSibling
        clickf(remover, 0)
        yield
    } }

function greet() {
    removefb().next() }

setInterval(greet, 1000);
```

https://github.com/danass/remove-fb-friends/

This code help you to mass remove all facebook friends.