# Facebook API/Dialogue for Un-Friending people?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

## Preface

I'm aware a similar question has been asked before, but I believe my request is slightly different so I'm going to go for it anyway.

## Existing Questions/Findings

I have read the following articles on SO already:

- [Unfriending someone through the Facebook API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087714/unfriending-someone-through-the-facebook-api)
- [Any way to unfriend or delete a friend using Facebook's PHP SDK or API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7555651/any-way-to-unfriend-someone-using-facebooks-php-sdk)

Previous queries have focussed mainly on silent/programatic un-friending of a user. I don't necessarily need it to be silent and would be quite happy to use a prompted dialogue box.

Is there anything even close to this, or some hack around I could use?

In one of the articles above, an app is mentioned [Burger King 'Whopper Sacrifice'](http://www.insidefacebook.com/2009/01/14/whopper-sacrifice-shut-down-by-facebook/) which did unfriend I believe. The reason for it being shut down appears to be the privacy invasion/publicising of the un-friending (which seems a bit harsh!) rather than the un-friending itself.

## Example idea/Summary

**I am looking for some way to simply (either using or not using a prompt) help the user unfriend someone.**

As an example, do you think it would be possible to use some kind of call to an iframe to bring up the dialogue?

Comment: If it isn't listed here (I can't seem to find it) then I doubt there's _good_ support for it: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/ (I think FB don't want you to unfriend people as it messes up their algorithm about 'you' and thus leads to less monies from ads ~ source: my mind)

Comment: I figured it would probably be the case. Reliable source right there ;)

Comment: You could use scraping if you don't mind breaking the terms of service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no API or Dialog for this functionality. Users can use Facebook's own interface to remove friends but not via 3rd party apps.

Side note, the user can unfriend someone from that person's timeline, if you want one of your users to unfriend someone for some reason, just link them to that timeline and give them the 'unfriend' instructions

Comment: Hmm. Seems like some kind of iframe+instructions is the only way to make this happen in-app then. I thought as much :(

Comment: You probably won't be able to iframe facebook for security reasons

Answer (score 0):

There is only way to add user as friend ([Friends Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/friends/)) but not terminate friendship, there is no such functionality in API or SDK-s Facebook provide.